# spring-test, groovy library and qualifier tag incompatibility

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-test

Im trying to add some groovy scripts to existing project and I stuck with making integration tests work. 
I have few beans marked with `<qualifier />` tag, that are used for autowiring both in test and in production code.

Right after I add 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
 (tried other versions aswell) to dependencies, without even any groovy usage, my integration tests stop working, with exception:

```
    SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5e5f7983] to prepare test instance [com.dph.groovy.vs.springtest.IntegrationTest@299c9fe7]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at 
......
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unexpected failure during bean definition parsing
    Offending resource: class path resource [spring/app-config.xml]
    Bean 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Tag 'qualifier' must have a 'type' attribute
    Offending resource: class path resource [spring/app-config.xml]
    Bean 'service'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:323)
```

Runnning project (with jetty 6 if this matters) doesnt cause any issues though, so I assume there's some trick with spring-test union with groovy.

I might just add 'type' to  my qualifiers, however it doesnt solve problem, because I have external dependencies with same qualifier tags configuration, besides this attribute is optional as far as I know.

I'd love to find out at least what are roots of this problem.

I created example project to reproduce the described question and will appreciate any ideas:
https://github.com/ametiste/groovy-vs-spring-test

Comment: Used `testCompile.exclude module: "groovy-all"`. Works for me since test configuration doesnt contain groovy parts. However if it ever will, the problem will come back

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: The full unedited stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: Please disregard my previous two comments. I was able to deduce that information from your example project.

Comment: Based on a quick analysis of your example project, it appears that you have discovered a bug in Spring's support for parsing XML configuration files with `GroovyBeanDefinitionReader`. I will investigate this further and get back to you.

Comment: @SamBrannen sorry for being late (and lazy with stacktraces). I originally used spring-integration 4.1.1 that is as far as i know includes spring 4.1.3 and tried several groovy versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered a bug in Spring's testing support.

**Fixed in Spring Framework 4.1.6 and 4.2 RC1**

I have fixed this bug for Spring Framework 4.1.6 (scheduled for release at the end of March 2015) and 4.2 (scheduled for release in Q3 2015). For further details, please see JIRA issue [SPR-12768](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12768).

If you wish to try out the fix before the aforementioned releases, consider building against one of the upcoming nightly snapshots.

**Temporary Work-around**

In the meantime, (*for XML configuration files that you are permitted to edit*) you can circumvent this bug by explicitly setting the `type` attribute in the `<qualifier>` tag to the intended *default* value which is `"org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier"`. See the following XML config for an example.

```
<bean id="foo" class="java.lang.String" c:_="bar">
    <qualifier value="foo" type="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier" />
</bean>
```

Regards,

Sam
*(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*